# Swift Real - How to append data to Object which was created in different class

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have a problem when I try to add value to Object which was created in different class.
That is my DB model:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class User: Object {

    @objc dynamic var height : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var age : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var sex : String = ""
    @objc dynamic var physicalActivity : Float = 1.0
    @objc dynamic var goal : String = ""
    var meals = List<Meals>()
    var weightProgress = List<WeightProgress>()
    var calories = List<Calories>()

    func calculateBMI() -> Double {

        let BMI : Double = (self.weightProgress.last?.weight)! / (Double(self.height / 100) * Double(self.height / 100))
        return BMI

    }

    func calculateBMR() -> Double {

        var calories : Double = 0.0
        let currentWeight = self.weightProgress.last?.weight
        let height = self.height
        let age = self.age

        if self.sex == "Mężczyzna" {
            calories += 66
            calories += (13.7 * currentWeight!)
            calories += Double(5 * height)
            calories -= (6.76 * Double(age))
        }
        else {
            calories += 655
            calories += (9.6 * currentWeight!)
            calories += Double(1.8 * Double(height))
            calories -= (4.7 * Double(age))
        }

        return calories

    }

}

class Meals: Object {

    @objc dynamic var mealsCount : Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var meal1 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal2 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal3 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal4 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal5 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal6 : String?
    @objc dynamic var meal7 : String?

}

class WeightProgress : Object {

    @objc dynamic var date : String?
    @objc dynamic var weight : Double = 0.0

}

class Calories : Object {

    @objc dynamic var date : String?
    @objc dynamic var eatenCalories : Int = 0

}

func getDateWithoutTime() -> String {

    let date = NSDate()

    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

    return dateFormatter.string(from: date as Date)

}
```

On One VC I create an User object and set some data (height, age, sex, goal type, number of meals), on second VC I want to extend User object by adding information about weight, and append weightProgress list by another object (WeightProgress). How should I make a reference to existing User object, when I try to set weight data and append weightProgress list?

Thanks
iMat

Comment: You can update the data if you want, and by doing this, you save the object from it in the second  VC

Comment: for ex: `user.meals.realm.write { // update info here or add new object to meals }`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize an object of that particular class and access the elements of the class.

Comment: Objects initialized. After that I try:
                try! realm.write {
                user.weightProgress.append(weightProgress)
                user.physicalActivity = convertActivityTypesForValue(activityType: activityTextField.text!)
            }

It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have several options for passing the object around, but I believe the best one is to save the object in Realm, and fetch it in the other controller, make the desired changes and save it again.

Comment: Appending to list in realm is performed only in write transaction.